# I'm trying to declare constants with a dynamically generated name

Tags: javascript

So, I wanted to automate some of my coding process. I figured maybe I don't have to manually name all the constants that refer to classes, and have a function do that. Here's my code, which, I feel, should work. Of course it doesn't. Should it? If not, why not?

```
function definitions() {
    var allElem = document.querySelectorAll("*"); //Get every HTML element.
    
    for(a = 0; a < allElem.length; a++) { //Iterate through every HTML element.
        
        if (allElem[a].classList.length == 0) { //If an element has no class...
            
            console.log("no var declared, " + a); //...ignore it.       
        
        } else { //If it has one or more classes...
            
            for(b = 0; b < allElem[a].classList.length; b++) { //...iterate through the classList.
                eval("const " + allElem[a].classList[b] + " = " + "document.getElementsByClassName('" + allElem[a].classList[b] + "');"); //Declare a constant named for the class if refers to
                console.log("const " + allElem[a].classList[b] + " = " + "document.getElementsByClassName('" + allElem[a].classList[b] + "');");                
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('clone').length); //This logs 10, which is correct.
    console.log(clone.length); // 'Uncaught ReferenceError: clone is not defined'. But... but... I thought I did... :'(
}
```

Comment: That's an extraordinarily strange approach, and I don't see it adding anything useful... better to do things normally (just select elements as you need to use them) IMO

Comment: @MennoDokter please provide clarity and some examples.

Comment: Please add html as well

Comment: "*automate some of my coding process*" - are you trying to generate code (that you can copy-paste in the actual application, and then adjust to fit), or are you really trying to create "dynamic constants"?

Comment: The `eval` does not work since the `const` declaration is scoped to the evaluated block.

Comment: Well... I don't how to further clarify it, sorry. The second console.log outputs "const clone = document.getElementsByClassName('clone');" Which works fine if I input it manually.

Comment: Why do you need so many constants in the first place? And, if you really do, can't you just make an object with a bunch of properties and then freeze it?

Comment: @Bergi thanks, that was it... Now I can get crackin' on a solution (I hope...)

Comment: It’s not clear that this approach makes much sense. Development happens in an IDE/editor, this code runs in the browser *(presumably)* —at what point would you be using any of these objects?